# Samsung Galaxy S3 with USB Keyboard and Google Keyboard

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb-on-the-go, external-keyboard, gboard

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 (SGH-I747), running Stock 4.4.2, non-rooted.

I prefer the Google Keyboard from the Play Store over the stock Samsung Keyboard.

Lately, I've been connecting a USB Keyboard to the device with a USB-OTG cable, which works great, but unfortunately causes my keyboard to reset every time to the stock Samsung keyboard, which remains the default keyboard, even when I disconnect the USB keyboard.

1) Is there any way to have it not switch back to the Samsung keyboard when I connect the USB Keyboard, and just keep having it use the Google Keyboard?

2) If not, is it possible to have it switch back automatically to the Google Keyboard when I disconnect the USB Keyboard?

I'm willing the root the phone, if necessary, to achieve this. Any advice you might have would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try disabling the Samsung Keyboard?

Comment: I don't see any way to disable the stock keyboard, only select another as the default (which goes back when you connect the USB keyboard). Do you know if rooting would allow you to disable the stock keyboard?

Comment: Settings > Applications > Application Manager then locate the Samsung Keyboard. Yes rooting will allow even to remove it from the phone.

Comment: Looks like root might even be required to Disable - the button itself is disabled.

Comment: Go to this thead and download the tool. No root required. The tool hides the app instead of removing it. http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/debloater-remove-carrier-bloat-t2998294